# Is there a way to shrink a Log File in SQL Server without affecting Point in Time Recovery?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My friend (who doesn't use stackoverflow) asked me a peculiar and interesting question just now.

Is there a way to "disconnect a Log file, or shrink a log file without affecting Point in Time Recovery"? as I quote his exact words. He is working against a live system, and somehow, the Log file has grown to 72GB

All I know is you can Delete a log file (as indicated in the snippet below from technet)

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
REMOVE FILE test1dat4;
GO
```

And Truncate it

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<log_file_name_Log>)
BACKUP LOG <database> WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<log_file_name_Log>)
```

I am no SQL Server wiz, and from my experience which I have, I cannot help him - though this is something I want to know the answer myself -

Any advice?

Comment: TRUNCATE_ONLY shouldn't work anymore. Have you seen [this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)? You should probably read that *in full* before starting to come up with your own hacks...

Comment: No, I just joined this site :)